# Execute Anonymous; Invalid type error

Tags: force.com, class, force.com-ide, invalid

I have very simple class **BankAcct**. I want to create an object of this class in Execute Anonymous and I got an **error: Invalid type**.

[image]

Any idea why it doesn't work?
Thx

Comment: Is your 'Active Project' in the Execute Anonymous window set to a project in the IDE which is connected to the environment (sandbox or production) that currently has your `BankAcct` class?

Comment: I used my user login and password which I used to log in to salesforce.com. Field environment is set to 'Production/Developer Edition'. But i didn't create any custom objects in salesforce (for example BankAcct).

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question (or perhaps I'm misunderstanding yours).

Your screenshot shows `BankAcct.cls`. There is a cuation symbol at the top of this class in your IDE, indicating that this class may have only been saved locally.

Assuming this class does exist on one of your Salesforce environments, does the 'Active Project' in the execute anonymous window match the project in your IDE that contains `BankAcct.cls`?

Comment: I didn't understand your question :) yes, you're right. Do I have to save it on the server to test it in Execute Anonymous?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. Though in some cases you can copy/paste your class code directly into the Execute Anonymous window and have it run.

Comment: In my understanding, I should be logged to server because I am using the same credentials as in logging to salesforce.com. Could you tell me how should I do it properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30743/discussion-between-k4sia-and-derek-f).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your provided screenshot, it looks like you have a warning on `BankAcct.cls`

From our chat, this was a 'File only saved locally, not to server' warning which indicates that there's likely something wrong with your project properties in the Force.com IDE. Unfortunately, I'm not well equipped to help you resolve that particular issue.

When using the Execute Anonymous feature in Force.com IDE, it runs the code you've provided in the 'Execute Anonymous' window in Salesforce itself (i.e. it doesn't run locally).

Thus, to be able to have your anonymous apex run succesfully, `BankAcct.cls` would need to be saved to Salesforce's servers.

There are a few potential workarounds you could try:

- Create and Edit an Apex class, BankAcct, through the Developer Console. This would get the `BankAcct` class into your org so you could test it via anonymous apex
- Your class is simple enough, right now, that it could be directly copy/pasted into the Execute Anonymous window

  ```
  public class BankAcct{
      public BankAcct(){
          // some constructor code
      }
  }

  BankAcct testBankAccount = new BankAcct();
  ```

Comment: Project->Properties->Force.com->Save to server. That's the solution. I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot @Derek !

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
BankAcct__c b = new BankAcct__c();
```

Comment: Are you getting the same error ? I assume you have BankAcct__c object and you have access to the object ?

Comment: I didn't create anything through GUI, I have only one class with a name BankAcct and I want to create its object in Execute Anonymous. Yes, error is the same. I want to create BankAcct object. BUt this is my first touch of force.com IDE so probably i am doing stupid mistake somewhere

Comment: May be this post will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491541/salesforce-script-to-create-custom-object-and-fields